# Two data sets with time series plot on one graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TTuC.png)Here I have two data sets with time series. I want plot that two data set in one figure by using matlab and I tried to plot it and it's coming as an error. Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Here I upload the code:

```
x={'6:15','9:25 ','11:00 ','13:50 ','16:25','19:00 ','20:00 ','22:05 ','23:40 '}; %time
y=[141 95 149 85 135 63 111 115 287]                % values
time_out=datenum(x,'HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
figure
plot(time_out,y,'.-')            
datetick('x','HH:MM')
hold on
x4={'6:58','9:50 ','11:45 ','13:40','15:45','17:40 ','18:35 ','22:15 ','00:08 '}; %time
y4=[116 118 252 142 159 185 162 130 204]                % values
out4=datenum(x4,'HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
figure
plot(out4,y4,'.-')            
datetick('x4','HH:MM')
```

and my graph is not proper also.

Comment: the last line `datetick('x4','HH:MM')` -> `datetick('x','HH:MM')`

Comment: Thank you for the response and I tried it and two graphs came in one figure.But my second graph is not proper . Because my time is early morning 12.08 value is going to other corner. Here I attach the image link...([1]: i.stack.imgur.com/8TTuC.png) I need that last time value into other side of the figure. Can you give me any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Just move the last value in x4 and y4 to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either just remove the second figure, or provide an explicit figure id. 
I prefer the latter, to prevent a larger amount of windows popping up:

```
x={'01:6:15','01:9:25 ','01:11:00 ','01:13:50 ','01:16:25','01:19:00 ','01:20:00 ','01:22:05 ','01:23:40'}; %time
y=[141 95 149 85 135 63 111 115 287];                % values
time_out=datenum(x,'dd:HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
figure(1); clf; hold on;
plot(time_out,y,'.-')            

x4={'01:6:58','01:9:50 ','01:11:45 ','01:13:40','01:15:45','01:17:40','01:18:35','01:22:15','02:00:08'}; %time
y4=[116 118 252 142 159 185 162 130 204];                % values
out4=datenum(x4,'dd:HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
figure(1); %just in case you created a second figure somewhere inbetween
plot(out4,y4,'.-')            
datetick('x','HH:MM')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and I tried it and two graphs came in one figure.But my second graph is not proper . Because my time is early morning 12.08 value is going to other corner. Here I attach the image link...([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TTuC.png)  I need that last time value into other side of the figure. Can you give me any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: If you just want to fix this for this specific issue, I would just change your second time - axis to `x4={'6:58','9:50 ','11:45 ','13:40','15:45','17:40 ','18:35 ','22:15 ','24:08 '}; ` 

A little bit nicer however would be, if you include the day in the time-vector:

`x={'00:6:15','00:9:25 ','00:11:00 ','00:13:50 ','00:16:25','00:19:00 ','00:20:00 ','00:22:05 ','00:23:40'}; %time
y=[141 95 149 85 135 63 111 115 287];                % values
time_out=datenum(x,'dd:HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
`

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid the extra `figure` command.

```
figure
plot(time_out,y,'.-')            
datetick('x','HH:MM')
hold on
x4={'6:58','9:50 ','11:45 ','13:40','15:45','17:40 ','18:35 ','22:15 ','00:08 '}; %time
y4=[116 118 252 142 159 185 162 130 204]                % values
out4=datenum(x4,'HH:MM');  %convert time to datenum
plot(out4,y4,'.-')            
datetick('x4','HH:MM')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and I tried it and two graphs came in one figure.But my second graph is not proper . Because my time is early morning 12.08 value is going to other corner. Here I attach the image link, ([1]: i.stack.imgur.com/8TTuC.png) I need that last time value into other side of the figure. Can you give me any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Put the data and time together and then convert it to the datenum.

Comment: I tried it but graph is not coming properly. Here I upload the code                                                                             day1= ['09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'09/06/2018';'10/06/2018']
x4={ '6:58','9:50 ','11:45 ','13:40','15:45','17:40 ','18:35 ','22:15 ','00:08'}; %time
y4=[116 118 252 142 159 185 162 130  204  ];
ns = datenum(day1) + datenum(x4);
ns = datenum(day1, 'dd/mm/yy') + datenum(x4, 'HH:MM') ;

Comment: Put the date and time in a single string like this 'datenum('09/06/2018 6:58','dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM')'

And if you wanna put them separately, 

'day1= {'09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','09/06/2018','10/06/2018'} 
x4={ '6:58','9:50 ','11:45 ','13:40','15:45','17:40 ','18:35 ','22:15 ','00:08'}; 
time y4=[116 118 252 142 159 185 162 130 204 ]; 
 ns = datenum([day1{1} x4{1}],'dd/mm/yyyyHH:MM');'